# Magento 2 have Tier price reduce Special price?

Tags: magento2, tierprice, advanced-pricing

Is it possible in **Magento 2** to have the **Tier Price** for a **product** also reduce the **Special Price**?

For example, if we had a product with **tier pricing** setup that when you **order** 3 or more it applies a **discount of 10%** we then added a **special price** of say **$1**, could the tier price be applied on **top of this**?

e.g.

```
Type            Quantity    Price
Normal Price    1           2.50
Normal Price    3+          2.25
Special Price   1           1
Special Price   3+          0.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKAIK - **By default Tier pricing is not supporting for special price !!**

**Meaning it is only available for main price only !!**

**Tier Price is only works on Main price - like 1 product in 10$ but if you wanted to give discount for 3 products then it works like 3 product in 8$**

But with special pricing it will not works defaultly !! you need to do customization on the same !!